# Binding parent properties on parameter with FromBody attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have an issue with binding from body parameters with inheritence. My object looks like this :

```cs
public class Person : BaseModel
{
  public int Name { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

with the parent class having an id for concurrency management :

```cs
public class BaseModel
{
  public int RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

On the controller side something like that :

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> SavePersonInformationsAsync([FromBody] Person person)
...
```

My `RowVersion` property is always at 0 despite other properties correctly set. The rowVersion appears in the request payload along other properties too. Am I missing something, aren't inherited properties binded too?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the object you're sending to the `SavePersonInformationsAsync` action?

Comment: @PlamenYordanov Fixed, we had a weird value converter which broke the binding so I had to decorate the property accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, we had a weird value converter which broke the binding so I had to decorate the property accordingly.